# How I can avoid from duplication of products with same Product ID

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

How I can avoid from duplication of products with same Product ID in file handling, please anyone can tell me the code for it
............................................................................................................................................................

```
struct Product
{
    int Pid;
    char Pname[55];
    int balance;
};

void AddProduct()
{
    Product p;

    cout <<"\nProduct ID: ";
    cin>>p.Pid;
    cout <<"Product Name: ";
    cin>>p.Pname;
    cout <<"Balance: ";
    cin>>p.balance;

    ofstream ofs("Products.bin");
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(p));
    ofs.close();
    cout <<"\nProduct Successfully Saved";
}

ProductOpt()
{
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        cout <<"\n1. Add Product"<<endl;    
        cout <<"2. Display All Products"<<endl;
        cout <<"3. Modify Product"<<endl;
        cout <<"4. Delete Product"<<endl;
        cout <<"5. Back"<<endl;
        ch = getch();
        cout<<endl;

        if(ch == '1')
            AddProduct();       
        else if(ch == '2')
            DisplayProduct();
        else if(ch == '3')
            ModifyProduct();
        else if(ch == '4')
            DeleteProduct();
        else if(ch == '5')
            break;
        else
            cout <<"Invalid Option"<<endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where'd it go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After taking the input, just open your file in read mode first, run a loop till end of file and check the Id with ids stored in the file. If it matches then print that it is a duplicate Id and call the function again to input data again. If loop terminates at end of file, open file in write mode and append the structure data to the file.

Comment: I not want to write nor print duplicate products to my binary file,